# How to iterate through rows from multiple text files and extract values in a table.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a script to iterate through multiple log files and want to extract information from certain rows and display it as a formatted table for checking all the values , rows from the first column to be used as column names and the values appended to these columns.

file_1:

```
   TRACE HEADER=========================================
                    min max
   col_1 [001-004]: 42  55
   col_2 [001-005]: 34  58
   col_3 [001-006]: 94  51
   col_4 [001-007]: 43  27
   col_5 [001-008]: 14  95
   -------------------------------------
```

file_2:

```
   TRACE HEADER=========================================
                    min max
   col_1 [001-004]: 43  55
   col_2 [001-005]: 39  58
   col_3 [001-006]: 91  51
   col_4 [001-007]: 48  25
   col_5 [001-008]: 14  96
   -------------------------------------
```

I have already tried iterating through the rows to extract the first column of the text file as column headers and extracting the other values as a list .

```
import re 
file = "f.txt"


TRC_BEGIN = "TRACE HEADER==="
TRC_END = "---------------"

col_names = []

istrace = False
traceLineCount = 0

log = open(file, "r")

for line in log:

    if line.startswith(TRC_BEGIN):
        istrace = True
    if istrace:
       traceLineCount = traceLineCount + 1
    if istrace and traceLineCount > 2:
       col = re.split("\[\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\]:\s", line)
       #print(col)
       col_1= col[0].strip()
       col_names.append(col_1)
   if line.startswith(TRC_END):
       istrace = False

del col_names[-2:]
```

Expected out put :

```
         col_1    col_2    col_3    col_4    col_5
file_1   42-55    34-58    94-51    43-27    14-95
file_2   43-55    39-58    91-51    48-25    14-96
```

Comment: you can format the files for easier use using `awk` like so --> `cat foo.txt | grep col_* | awk -F " " '{ print $1, $3, "-", $4 }'`

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to handle all string operations in a singe regex transaction. You can do this my capturing the the desired data in capture groups. So a solution might look like this.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path


p = re.compile(r'(col_\d+).*?:.(\d+).*?(\d+).*')
results = {}
files = ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']
for file in files:
    if not Path(file).exists():
        continue
    d = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            m = p.search(line)
            if m:
                d[m.group(1)] = f'{m.group(2)}-{m.group(3)}'
    results[file] = d


print(results) #{'test.txt': {'col_1': '42-55', 'col_2': '34-58', 'col_3': '94-51', 'col_4': '43-27', 'col_5': '14-95'}}
```